# access to docker shell inside one of containers

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm running a project in a container on my machine. this project needs to list other containers on machine. previously this project was on machine (not on a container in machine) and it was possible to do that. but now it's in one of those containers. I want to know is it possible to create an access for this type of jobs (listing containers, stop/start/... them or any other works on other containers or the host machine)?
if it's true, how can it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use so-called `docker-in-docker` technique. But before starting with it, you are obligated to read the post:
http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

which is the best explanation of pros and cons.

All you have is to export `/var/run/docker.sock` to your container and setup docker-cli inside the container. It will give you `docker` access inside container, at the same time you will be adressing your host's docker engine.

Comment: no I don't have to use docker-in-docker. but the second part of your answer was interesting. I have another question. I have to give the ssh access of my containers to somebody (with exposing ssh port). is there any danger about hacking the machine from inside the docker (if i dont export the `/var/run/docker.sock` to containers ) @grapes

Comment: It all depends on your network settings for `docker`. With default settings, from inside container you can't access host's ports, because you live in separate network.